# Como faço para colorir um icon com degrade, quero colorir apenas a imagem e não seu background, obrigado

Tags: html, css3, icons

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="social-icons">

                <a href="#" class="btn-face">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
          </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn-insta">
          <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
          </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn-whats">
          <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-lg"></i>
          </a>

    </div>

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .social-icons{
        float: right;
    }

    .social-icons a{
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 12px;
    }

    .btn-face:hover{
        color: blue;
    }

    .btn-insta:hover{
        color: red;
    }

    .btn-whats:hover{
        color: green;
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer o degradê com esse código:

```
.fa {
  color: #9c47fc;
  margin-left: 12px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Agora é só colocar as cores que você quer.

Comment: Deu certo, eu só tive que alterar algumas coisas:                                                                                                                                                                                              1°coloquei as definições direto no icon pq o: -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; estava fazendo o topo do icon desaparecer.                                                                                      2°Tirei o margin estava empurrando os icons, Assim ficou do jeito q

Comment: `.btn-insta:hover{
 color: red;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f7ce02, #f96302, #f71102, #d32155, #b43890, #904eca, #8944bb, #7832ae);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}`